# Load function Images doesn't recognize file

Tags: julia

I'am trying to load an image in Julia using the package Images and the function load.

```
julia> load("/train/1.bpm")
ERROR: FileIO.File{FileIO.DataFormat{:UNKNOWN}}("/train/1.bpm") couldn't be recognized by FileIO.
```

I am using Julia 0.4.2.

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: could it be because it doesn't recognize the extension .bmp, is that a valid image format?

Comment: This looks like a typo ("bpm" rather than "bmp"). See also https://github.com/JuliaIO/FileIO.jl/pull/54.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error statement:  `FileIO.DataFormat{:UNKNOWN}}("/train/1.bpm")`, the file extension is wrong. (`bpm` used instead of `bmp`).

Use the correct file format (`julia> load("/train/1.bmp")`) and you'll be good.